# Linq Expressions does not find a public method... :-/

Tags: .net, expression, dynamic-linq

I write a expression that will test if a property(enum) of a object have, or have not some flags set.

The code bellow test if the validity of an object "contains" or not Monday, using the HasFlag function of an Enum.

Actually, the Call method seems do not find a corresponding "HasFlag"... What I do wrong in the bellow code?

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression exp = null;

            var myValParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestHehe), "val");
            var myValTestValidityParam = Expression.Property(myValParam, "TestValidity");

            Validity myVal = Validity.Monday;

            // Gives 'True'
            Console.WriteLine(myVal.HasFlag(myVal));

            // test it
            var myConst = Expression.Constant(myVal, myVal.GetType());

            // here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            exp = Expression.Call(myValTestValidityParam, "HasFlag", null, myConst);
            // No method 'HasFlag' on type 'ConsoleApplication3.Validity' 
            // is compatible with the supplied arguments.

            // just to be
            Console.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class TestHehe
    {
        public Validity TestValidity { get; set; }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum Validity
    {
        Monday = 0,
        Tuesday = 1,
        Wednesday = 2,
        Thursday = 4,
        Friday = 8,
        Saturday = 16,
        Sunday = 32
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the expression do?

Comment: @Steven: Please read till the end... to-xanatos: The expression evaluates if a enum HasFlag, as you can see from code.

Comment: I don't see a question either.

Comment: I can't see where there is an instance of `TestHehe` here?

Comment: @BoltClock: if my last post phrase is not good enough, read it as "What is wrong with this code?"

Comment: If you want anyone to help you with *your* problem, please respect them by coming up with a clear description of your problem. Tell us what the problem is, what you tried so far. "What's wrong with this code" will never cut it. Why doesn't it work for you? Do you get an compiler error (if so, what error), or do you get a runtime exception (it so, please post the stack trace) or doesn't it behave the way you expect it to?

Comment: @chibacity: perhaps you can't see it. because there is no instance of TestHehe. No need. I just write an expression that will test objects of type TestHehe.

Comment: @Steven The error message is in the source code example...

Comment: @Steven I updated the post. But as for me, if you read the code, it is self explanatory... Surely, for people that understands it...

Comment: @serhio: Please read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) before posting another question here.

Comment: @Steven: Some people understood easier, others does not so. Not worth to comment not knowing the subject...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myConst = Expression.Constant(myVal, typeof(Enum));
// here!

exp = Expression.Call(myValTestValidityParam, "HasFlag", null, myConst);
```

Are you looking for this? `HasFlag` wants an `Enum` as the parameter, so I downcasted `myVal`.

Comment: so, what do you want do say... Validity is an Enum too! why it does not find an inherited type parameter?!

Comment: @serhio the signature of HasFlag is `bool HasFlag(Enum)`. Perhaps `Expression.Call` doesn't try to check for the base types of parameters, or perhaps it's because `enums` are strange beasts in .NET . I don't know.